# change value by key of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I think it is very easy and simple question. but it is very difficult for me. please help!
I can write R code

```
b$v2 <- ifelse(a$key==b$key, a$v2, b$v2)
```

input df
a is a df, it have key and answer value.
b is a df, it have to change according to a.

```
a1=[11,22,44]
a2=['a','b','d']
a3={'key':a1, 'v2':a2}
a=pd.DataFrame(a3)

b1=[11,22,33,44,55]
b2=['ff','gg','c','hh','e']
b3={'key':b1, 'v2':b2}
b=pd.DataFrame(b3)
```

final result (what I want)

```
c1=[11,22,33,44,55]
c2=['a','b','c','d','e']
c3={'key':c1, 'v2':c2}
c=pd.DataFrame(c3)
```

but I don't know how to write python.
I tried.

My concept

first, making True, False

```
i=1
a['key'].iloc[i]==b['key']
```

I have 5 bools (F, T, F, F, F)

second, When True value, Change 'v2' col of df b
but it is not working

```
b['v2'] = np.where(a['key'].iloc[i]==b['key'], a['v2'], b['v2'])
```

error message :

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (3,) (5,)
```

I think I have a misunderstanding using 'np.where' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we could use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for mapping `key` -> `v2`. Set `a`'s `key` as index using `set_index`. Now, use it in `Series.map`

```
m = a.set_index('key')['v2']
b['v2'] = b['key'].map(m).fillna(b['v2'])

print(b)
#    key v2
# 0   11  a
# 1   22  b
# 2   33  c
# 3   44  d
# 4   55  e
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way out would be to find what  of b is not in a and then append it to a.

```
c=a.append(b[~(b['key'].isin(a['key']))]).sort_values(by=['key'])
```

Long way out is to use outer merge, fill in missing using combine_first and then drop suffixed columns not wanted

```
c=b.merge(a, how='outer', on='key', suffixes=('_x',''))
c=c.assign(v2=c['v2'].combine_first(c['v2_x'])).drop(columns=['v2_x'])



   key v2
0   11  a
1   22  b
2   33  c
3   44  d
4   55  e
```

Comment: See edits for additional method if you wanted a oneliner

Answer (score 1):

Outer `merge` the two dataframes on `'key'` and then fill `NaN` values with values from `b` and drop the column from `b`:

```
out = a.merge(b, on='key', how='outer', suffixes=['','_y'])
out['v2'].fillna(out['v2_y'], inplace=True)
out.drop('v2_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Another option is to map `'v2'` values from `b` to `NaN`s in the merged dataframe:

```
out = a.merge(b[['key']], on='key', how='outer')
out['v2'].fillna(out['key'].map(b.set_index('key')['v2']), inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   key   v2
0   11    a
1   22    b
2   44    d
3   33    c
4   55    e
```

Comment: There can be several cases. Your answer is very helpful and exactly addresses my question. Thanks! But it only works fine if the data in a and b are different. If a and b are the same, the 'v2_y' column is not created and an error occurs. We can solve the problem by checking the existence of the column 'v2_y' using 'if, else...'.